# Maintain position of 'pins' on top of image when browser window resizes

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I want to put a few 'pins' on. I know how to get pins on the image, but the issue is that when the browser is resized, the image will scale but the pins won't stay match/stay on top of the desired position.

Does someone have an example of this type of functionality working?

Comment: The person who wrote this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bKbWf/ got close to figuring it out I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The fiddle you posted is correct. The image has to be wrapped into an element with a

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
```

Then inside you also put the pins with:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Then adjust the top and left based on where you wish to place them.

Comment: I you need an example let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like the <li>s in the fiddle are staying in the same place only some of the time. If you expand it out more you'll see them get dislocated.

Comment: That's because the container gets wider than the image. You need to add the display: inline-block to the parent of the image. I corrected my answer

Comment: Great! Thank you!